# How to use array in UseState hook in react and how to update it dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-state

I'm having this function component.

```js
import React,{useState} from "react";
import {Container,Row,Col} from "reactstrap";
import "../stylesheets/cart.css";
const Cart = ({image}) =>
{
    const [cartList,addItem] =useState([])
    if(image !== undefined)
    {
        return(
      <Container>
          <Row key={image.id}>
              <Col xs="6">
                  <img src={image.path} alt={image.name} className="img-thumbnail" />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="6" className="carttest">
                  <h3>{image.name}</h3>
                  <h4>{image.price}</h4>
              </Col>
          </Row>
      </Container>
        );
    }
```

I want  every time this method is called, I needs to add the incoming image object to be added to the end of  the array.
Thing I want to create if I sum it up is an array of objects in local state. That I can use to implement `filter()` and `map()` functions later.

Here every time the Cart method is called I want to use `addItem` function to keep adding the image object at the end of `cartList` array.

Can anyone give me a solution to this

Answer (score 1):

Solution to do this is trivial, but `Cart` isn't a method, it's a react component. If I understand your question, you are wanting to add `image` to local state when that prop updates. You can use an `useEffect` hook to handle this.

1. Use `useEffect` with `image` in dependency array to trigger effect callback.
2. Use a functional state update to shallow copy existing `cartList` array and append new image to the end of the array.

Cart

```
const Cart = ({ image }) => {
  const [cartList, addItem] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    image && addItem(cart => [...cart, image]); // <-- functional state update
  }, [image]); // <-- image dependency

  ...
};
```